# How to Resolve rebase conflicts in EGit

Tags: git, github, egit, rebase, pull

I am using GIT in eclipse. I have a branch where I made some code changes and committed them. Now, when I try to pull that branch it is giving error as below

[image]

Now, all my changes which are already Staged and Committed are again directly added to Staged changes. And I am end up in having three options in Git Staging View as below

[image]

> Abort: Cancels the pull and rebase operation
>   Skip Commit: Roll back all my changes and pulls (All my changes will lost)
>   Continue and Commit options are disabled.

So, here I have only chance to Abort, Skip Commit. But I need to pull the latest changes without losing my changes.

And this is my .gitconfig file

```
[user]  
name = name  
email = email  
[core]  
autocrlf = true  
[pull]  
rebase = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. Acutally, I have some classes with conflicts in Unstaged view box. That is why I am unable to do Continue other than 'Skip Commit/Abort'.
But, when I resolve my conflicts using the Merge Tool, then I can able to do Continue, Commit.